# NSURLConnection, using proxy server

Tags: iphone, proxy, nsurlconnection, socks

I want to POST using an NSURLConnection, using a SOCKS proxy along the way.

From what I've read, NSURLConnection does support SOCKS and HTTP proxies. The question is, where do I configure it?
I couldn't find any suitable method on e.g. NSURLRequest for configuring which proxy server to use.

If this is a limitation, does anyone know of a good replacement that does support SOCKS?

Comment: Have you got the right Solution?? Please let me know I have to consume Webservice... via SOCKS proxy

Comment: Sorry, no. I gave up on SOCKS and solved the problem in another way. I think that @Tommy's answer would have worked though, but I did not have time to try it out (I did this for a tech demo). Instead, I set up a relay HTTP server using Python/Twisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I've never used it myself, from reading around the topic I think you need to use an `NSOutputStream` rather than an `NSURLConnection`, which is toll-free bridged with `CFWriteStream`. On that you can use `CFWriteStreamSetProperty` with the `kCFStreamPropertySOCKSProxy` key and a dictionary with corresponding entries for the various keys defined [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketStreamRef/Reference/reference.html).